# Getting 'invalid character class' from regexp error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, amazon-rds

When I tried to execute following query in Adminer and Sequel Pro:

```
SELECT * FROM `sms_messages` WHERE `message` REGEXP '[^[:ascii:]]+'
```

I am getting following error in MYSQL:

```
Error in query (1139): Got error 'invalid character class' from regexp
```

However, it works in my local computer but not working in AWS RDS. In local I have installed XAMPP with MariaDB 10.1.37. I have MySQL 5.7.26 engine version in AWS RDS. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) for `REGEXP` (5.7 version, not 8.0), we can see that there is no supported `[:ascii:]` character set.  But, we can instead match all ASCII characters using the following hexadecimal range:

```
[\x00-\x7F]
```

Your updated query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sms_messages
WHERE CONVERT(message USING BINARY) REGEXP '[^\x00-\x7F]';
```